# why laravel-blade adds unwanted curly braces?

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-blade

I have stored form HTML in the relational database.
If I retrieve HTML content using the below syntax.

```
{{$content["form_content"]}}
```

I get
[this view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJ07b.png).

Instead, if I use

```
{{!! $content["form_content"] !!}}
```

I get [this view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhIFP.png) with unwanted curly braces.

Comment: Because you wrote wrong syntex, just use:  {!! $content["form_content"] !!}

Comment: The documentation: [Displaying Unescaped Data](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#displaying-unescaped-data)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
{!! $content["form_content"] !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use {{ }} meaning that you are escaping HTML entities. It prevents Cross-Site Scripting attacks because your input being displayed from your server/database.
If you use

```
{{!! "<b>some codes</b>" !!}}
```

then it spits
**some codes** which is not great idea to be shown for security sake.

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of mine using

```php
<?php echo $string->item; ?>
```

the ; at the end made all the difference.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).